# nv.d3 trigger tool tips for multiple graphs on the page at the same time

Tags: tooltip, nvd3.js

Right now with the stackedAreaChart() from the nv.d3 examples you get a tooltip when you hover on a point in the timeseries.

I've aligned 3 time series vertically. If the mouse hovers over a point on any of them, I would like to see the tooltip for each graph for that corresponding point.

Photo shows the current behavior.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about coding it but surely all it should be is linking the x co-ordinate at the pointers location so at `06/10/06 on graph one` show the tooltip at `06/10/06 on graphs one, two and three`

I'm not sure how much this will help, just throwing my thoughts at the page.

Thanks, steve.